# What do I need to do to DataMapper to have a persistent sqlite database?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, orm, sinatra, datamapper

Here's what I'm using to create my database:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default,"sqlite://my.db")

   class Model1

      property :some_prop,String
      ...
      property :other_prop,String
   end

   DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

I'm using this in combination with Sinatra. Everything's ok while the script is running, I can use my objects normally. However, I see no file `my.db` on the disk, and everytime I'm restarting the application, I start from scratch, without any objects.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a specification for these URIs? Mine (like yours) has a relative path, and it ain't working. I don't know what these URIs are called. Are they a general sqlite thing, or a specific datamapper-sqlite thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the full path in there (note there are 3 forward slashes):

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite:///path/to/my/database/my.db")
```

Then you should see `my.db` under `/path/to/my/database/`

Comment: This works nice on a Linux system. How could this be adapted for a Windows solution? Or how can I specify on the path that I want to use the current directory?

Comment: `DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/db.sqlite")` should do the trick.

Comment: Or simply `File.expand_path(relative_path)`

Comment: There is a difference between `"#{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/#{relative_path}"` and `File.expand_path(relative_path)`: First one will resolve the path relative to the current *.rb file, the latter will resolve the path relative to the the current working directory (`pwd`)

Answer (score 0):

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/my.db")
# your schema

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

Also see [docs.](http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html)